# Is Flink Map State Access with RocksDB backend Lazy?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

```
    MapState<String, Integer> someMapState;
    ...

    public void processElement(String s, Context context, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        // Store stuff into map
        Streams.stream(someMapState.values()).forEach(collector::collect);

    }
```

Is State access like `MapState.values()` lazy(values are not loaded to memory all at once) for RocksDB backend?

Does this behavior vary depending on State type(ValueState, ListState, and so on.)?

Note: I tried digging through docs and source code but could not find any details regarding this, any pointers would be appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RocksDB state backend keeps its working state on disk, as serialized bytes, with an off-heap (in memory) block cache. Ser/de is required on every state access/update.

With MapState, each entry in the Map is a separate RocksDB object, allowing for efficient reads and writes of map entries. ListState is a single object, but the RocksDB state backend can append to ListState simply by appending the serialized bytes of the new entry.

Internally, `org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBMapState#values` uses a `RocksDBMapIterator`, which does not load all of the values into memory at once. It works through the keyspace in chunks, which it caches. (And for what it's worth, it iterates over the keys in sorted, binary order.)

With ListState, the entire list does need to fit onto the heap, and its serialized value can't exceed 2^31 bytes.

If you are using RocksDB with incremental checkpoints, then checkpoints are highly optimized, as all that is required is to copy any new (immutable) SST files to the durable file storage (and to delete any SST files that are no longer relevant due to compaction).

When restoring from incremental checkpoints, state is only lazily loaded. If local recovery is enabled, then all that is needed is to copy any missing SST files from the remote, durable file store, so in many cases, recovery can be almost immediate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation David and including the Class Name! I am trying to implement a large fanout(1:N Join) using KeyedCoProcessFunction and internally using MapState. I am curious about the 2^31 bytes limit that you mention for List State. What are the theoretical limits for Map State? Is the limit only be the total size or there is a different limit for the number of records as well? Would highly appreciate If you could point me to a doc if any(PS: Would be glad to post this as a separate question if you prefer it)

Comment: All keys and values in RocksDB are limited to 2^31 bytes. And I believe Flink's rocksdb iterator will try to fill its cache with 128 entries. Those are the only limits I can think of for MapState. https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Tuning-Guide may help.

Comment: Thank you for the reference