# Iterating over list state with millions of records in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to store all the CDC records in list state and streams those records to respective sinks once trigger message is received.

The list state can grow up-to a million records, will iteration over the list state in `KeyedProcessFunction` causes memory issues? Planning to use RocksDB state backend to store the state. What is the correct way of streaming the list state in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding memory usage of `ListState` this answer explains how memory is used with the `RocksDB` state backend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622888/19059974

It seems that the whole list will need to fit into heap, so depending on the size of your elements, it could take a lot of memory.

Ideally, you would want to key the state into smaller partitions, so it can be spread when increasing the task parallelism. Alternatively, a workaround could be to use a `MapState` which seems to not load all its contents into memory when iterating over the map. It will use more storage than a `ListState` and most likely appending won't be as fast, but should allow you to iterate over it using less memory.

Comment: thats for the comment. I want the entries to be ordered based on the event time, is it possible to maintain in the `MapState` ?

Comment: `And for what it's worth, it iterates over the keys in sorted, binary order.`

So if the key is the event time, it should work as you want